# Updating stock in products table after till payment received

Tags: java

I am trying to update the quantity in stock of any items that are sold from a till. I have an SQL database which holds products for sale. When I sell a product or a number of products in one transaction, I need the stock level to reduce depending on the quantity sold. This is the code that I have tried so far but It does not do anything to the quantity in stock apart from taking away what has been hard coded in a method which is incorrect, I just need guidance on how to make it dynamic when an order is complete. Do I need an SQL update statement?

Thank You

```
// Setting values back to zero or null to begin processing another order and deduct stock depending on items sold


jbtNewOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(jbtNewOrder)) 
        {
              total = 0.0;
              totalTF.setText("");
              tenderedTF.setText("");
              changeTF.setText("");
              dtm.setRowCount(0);
              Stock s1 = new Stock();
              s1.deductStock(24);
        }
      }
});
```

/* Right now it will deduct the stock by 1 if product number 24 is sold or not sold which is incorrect, I need it to deduct the quantity of an item if it is sold on an order, When the new order button is clicked, it clears all the details from the previous order, at that point, it should deduct whatever was 
sold on the previous order*/

Comment: Please properly format your code.

Comment: It is more readable now